# want to make calculator in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i have bugs in my calcultor any one can change it ???
after enter any digit when i clicked on '-' button value cannot be set as value:''and not any operation perform but for button'+' it works perfectly 
here is my code of operation function where i perform my all operations

code of state

```
this.state = {
  value: '0',
  firstValue: 0,
  operation: '',
  previousvalue: '',
  nextvalue: '',
  counter: 0,
  showingTemporaryResult: false,
  newAnswere: '',
  updateValue: ''
}
```

and now here is code of my operation function and handleclick function where i handle my every input

```
handleclick(digit) {
  if (this.state.showingTemporaryResult) {
    //console.log("TRUE CALLED");
    this.setState({
      value: String(digit),
      showingTemporaryResult: false
    })
  } else {
    console.log("ELSE CALLED");
    this.setState({
      value: this.state.value === '0' ? String(digit) : this.state.value + digit
    });
  }


  // console.log('helo click fire',this.state.value);

}
operation(operator) {
  console.log('operator coming', operator);

  if (operator === '+') {
    // this.setState({operation:operator},()=>{console.log('setting immidiate state',this.state.operation)});

    if (this.state.operation === '+') {
      console.log("are u coming");
      let secondValue = parseInt(this.state.value);
      let firstValue = parseInt(this.state.firstValue);
      console.log('chcking first value ', firstValue);
      console.log('chcking second value ', secondValue);

      let sum = secondValue + firstValue;
      console.log('chcking sum value ', sum);

      this.setState({
          firstValue: sum,
          value: sum,
          secondValue: '',
          showingTemporaryResult: true
        },
        () => {
          console.log('first', this.state.firstValue, 'second', this.state.secondValue,
            'value===', this.state.value)
        });
      //console.log('somthing here ');

    } else if (this.state.operation === '-') {
      console.log("something coming");
      let secondValue = parseInt(this.state.value);
      let firstValue = parseInt(this.state.firstValue);
      console.log('chcking first value ', firstValue);
      console.log('chcking second value ', secondValue);

      let subanswer = secondValue - firstValue;
      console.log('chcking sum value ', subanswer);

      this.setState({
          firstValue: subanswer,
          value: subanswer,
          secondValue: '',
          showingTemporaryResult: true
        },
        () => {
          console.log('first', this.state.firstValue, 'second', this.state.secondValue,
            'value===', this.state.value)
        });
      //console.log('somthing here ');

    } else if (this.state.operation === '') {
      let firstValue = parseInt(this.state.value);
      this.setState({
        firstValue
      });;
      this.setState({
        value: '',
        operation: operator
      });
      // console.log('or here ');
    }

  } else if (operator === '=') {
    if (this.state.counter > 0) {
      let answer = parseInt(this.state.newAnswere) + parseInt(this.state.value);
      console.log('equal operator counter called', this.state.newAnswere, 'value', this.state.value);
      this.setState({
        value: answer
      });
      console.log("what is thhis value", this.state.value)
    } else if (this.state.operation === '+') {
      let answer = parseInt(this.state.value) + parseInt(this.state.firstValue);
      console.log('firstvalue', this.state.firstValue)
      console.log('value', this.state.value)
      console.log('answere', answer)
      this.setState({
        value: answer
      });
      this.setState({
        counter: 1,
        newAnswere: answer
      }, () => {
        console.log('newcounter', this.state.counter, 'newans', this.state.newAnswere)
      })
      console.log('value=', this.state.value)

    }

  }

}
```

This is my code can u guys please help me for this problem

Answer (score 0):

In your operation function you have this:

```
if(operator==='+'){
  if(this.state.operation === '+') {...}

  else if(this.state.operation === '-') {...}

}
else if(operator==='='){
}
```

Are you missing another else if:

```
else if(operator==='-'){...}
```